# Windows 10 not detecting Wi-Fi after booting Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu. That said, I recently broke Windows 10 in trying to move it to an SSD and now have a clean install.

Every time I boot Windows after previously booting Ubuntu, the Wi-Fi device refuses to work. The last time this happened, two reboots after uninstalling the device fixed it. This time, reboots did nothing, and for whatever reason, entering and exiting sleep mode fixed it.

I noticed before sleep mode fixed it, my Bluetooth was working (and on for some reason). The Bluetooth runs off of the Wi-Fi chip (Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377), so I don't know why it would work if the computer thinks the Wi-Fi chip is not connected.

Is there some way to keep the Wi-Fi from breaking, or at least from resetting my saved passwords at the very least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laptop decided to cooperate. Not sure if there's really a solution to be had here...

Comment: I feel like I should delete the question since it doesn't really help anyone, but the site doesn't seem to think that's a good idea... why'd I have to set an answer :|